# Xcode - RSS reader

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, feed, xcode6.1

Recently I have been trying to follow a tutorial on how to make an RSS Reader App in Xcode 6 beta, although I am using Xcode 6.1. I came across a line which appeared to be an error.

The full code is:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var parser = NSXMLParser()
var feeds = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var ftitle = NSMutableString()
var link = NSMutableString()
var fdescription = NSMutableString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    feeds = []
    var url: = NSURL(string: "http://www.mentonegrammar.net/rss/news")!
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
    parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
    parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
    parser.parse()
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, 
            namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, 
            attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    element = elementName

    // instantlate

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, 
            namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {

}

func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser!) {

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0
}

/*
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
*/



}
```

The error is:

```
var url: = NSURL(string: "http://www.mentonegrammar.net/rss/news")!
```

It says Swift `Compiler Error - Expected Type`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the fact that your declaration is wrong.

Swift allows you to force a variable to a specific type (instead of Swift auto-determining the type) by typing `var foo : String`, you get a variable named foo, of type String. To remove your error, either type

`var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mentonegrammar.net/rss/news")!`

or type

`var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.mentonegrammar.net/rss/news")!`

Also, a tutorial I greatly appreciated on building an RSS reader in xCode can be found at: http://www.appcoda.com/building-rss-reader-using-uisplitviewcontroller-uipopoverviewcontroller/